# Problems with generating a random integer in C using the modulus operator

Tags: c

I've written a function intended to use the modulus operator to output a random number between 1 and a variable named sum and analyze the value based on the range within which the random number falls. I've been running into trouble with the function, though: I used the following line of code to output the random number.

```
random = rand()%sum + 1
```

However, for some reason, I get extremely high numbers that don't fall within the range. I've seeded the function in the main program before calling the function, so I don't understand why it's not working. Any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks!

EDIT: Here's the function in my program:

```
int comp_output (int row, int array[][3], int sum) {
    int random;
    random = rand()%sum + 1;

    if (random <= array[row][0]) {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (random >= sum - array[row][2] + 1) {
        return 2;
    }
    else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

The array is initialized before the function is called, so that's not the problem. Does anything look wrong with the function as I've presented it? Thanks to everyone who's helped so far!

Comment: Aside from the missing semicolon, that line looks fine. Maybe you need to include more of your program.

Comment: Well, and ignoring the fact that you're destroying whatever vestige of randomness was there in the first place. Besides those two things, yeah, looks great. Must be your other code that's also wrong.

Comment: Notice that if `RAND_MAX%sum!=0`,the probability of occurrence of each integer `i` are not equal. Integers below `RAND_MAX%sum` have a slightly higher probability to occur. It can be bypassed by skipping number above `(RAND_MAX/sum)*sum`. The most probable issue is that this line is part of a function `void myrand(int sum,int random)` which should be `void myrand(int sum,int* random)` and the corresponding line should be `*random=...`. More code is needed to provide you with a good answer.

Comment: @Blindy: How does that "destroy... whatever vestige of randomness was there in the first place"?

Comment: Are you sure that `sum` has the value you think it does? Show more code, preferably a complete self-contained program that exhibits the problem. http://sscce.org/

Comment: Assuming `sum` has a reasonable value, the tiny fragment of code you've shown us *should* do what you want. Something else is going wrong. Once you figure out that part, there can still be some serious problems with the simple `rand() % whatever` approach. See section 13 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/), particularly the questions about random numbers.

Comment: "get extremely high numbers" Where do you get them? How do you observe them?

Comment: @n.m. I ran the program a few times with a printf function added immediately after the value of the random variable was calculated. The numbers got as high as around 900.

Comment: What is the value (or range) of `sum`?

Comment: The initial value is 30 and it changes depending on what the function returns.

Comment: Please show actual code and its expected output and actual output in the body of the question.

Comment: @KeithThompson, modulo on an (almost) normally distributed RNG biases it towards the first part of the resulting sequence. As opposed to simply dividing by the maximum value and using the floating point range 0-1, where the error is uniformly distributed when using it to generate discrete numbers.

Comment: @Blindy: Sure -- but that hardly *destroys* any randomness. If `sum` is small compared to `RAND_MAX`, the bias could be insignificant -- or even nonexistent if `RAND_MAX+1` is a multiple of `sum`. And it wouldn't explain results outside the range `0` .. `sum-1` -- which is what the OP seems to be implying.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong in your program. I tested your function and indeed if I add printf("%d\n", random); to it and if sum is 5, then the value can be either 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5 but nothing else. I don't understand what your problem is, but it is not in the line of code you highlighted. It generates random numbers between 1 (inclusive) and sum (inclusive). However, you didn't provide the full code so it isn't possible to understand from your limited code what the real purpose of the full comp_output function is.

Do note that using the low-order bits of the rand() implementation may not necessarily be a good idea. rand()%2 on many systems provides an alternating sequence 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, ... The real fix is obviously to use a better random number generator such as the Mersenne Twister (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister) or PCG (http://www.pcg-random.org/).